# store numeric input from text field in array in android

Tags: android

I am new in android programming. I making statistics app in which I want to calculate mean for this.

I have to take the input from a user in text field separated by (,) and store in an array. How can I do this?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_ans=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_ans);
    b_mean=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b_mean) ;

   b_mean.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public  void onClick(View v) {
            String input = et_input.getText().toString();
            int Length = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int arr[] = new int[Length];

            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                sum += arr[i];
                et_ans.setText(sum);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: many ways to do it, simplest , split on `,` then parse one by one

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
String s = et_input.getText().toString();
                    String[] spitString = s.split(",");
                    float total = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < spitString.length; i++) {
                        total = total + Float.parseFloat(spitString[i]);
                    }
                    float mean = total / spitString.length; // your mean value
```

But make sure your input in edit text is `integer`, `float` value with , separated.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand, you want to calculate mean.
**For example :**
**Input :** 10,20,30
**Desired Output :** 10+20+30/3=40

If Yes then you can do by following these steps.
First of all take values from `EditText` and store in an array by doing this :

```
b_mean=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b_mean);

//Do this in onClickListener.
String[] values=b_mean.getText.toString().split(',');
```

This above code will get all values in **values array** by using split function.

Then run a loop to calculate mean like this :

```
//Do this in onClickListener.
float sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                sum += Float.parseFloat(arr[i]);      
     }
float mean =sum/values.length;
et_ans.setText(mean+"");

//This [""] used to convert float value into string. you can either use String.valueOf(mean).
```

That's it!!